# How do I update values in a json string using jq?

Tags: json, jq, to-json, fromjson

I have a JSON file with content this:-

```
{
  "content": "{\"accountNumber\":\"12345\",\"transactionId\":\"568\",\"socialSecurityNumber\":\"123456796\",\"identificationNumber\":1,\"securityCode\":\"1234\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"1000-01-01\",\"firstName\":\"qwerty\",\"lastName\":\"xyz\",\"balance\":123}",
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "createdAt": "2020-11-11T12:55:41.350+0000",
  "cryptoKeyId": null
}
```

I just want to update the value of **firstName**.
End result I want is

```
{
  "content": "{\"accountNumber\":\"12345\",\"transactionId\":\"568\",\"socialSecurityNumber\":\"123456796\",\"identificationNumber\":1,\"securityCode\":\"1234\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"1000-01-01\",\"firstName\":\"abcdef\",\"lastName\":\"xyz\",\"balance\":123}",
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "createdAt": "2020-11-11T12:55:41.350+0000",
  "cryptoKeyId": null
}
```

I tried this

```
 ( .content | fromjson.firstName = "abcdef"  )
```

but no success.
Can you help me here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to update the value, you would use `|=`, and don’t forget the call to `tojson`:

```
.content |= (fromjson | (.firstName = "abcdef") | tojson)
```

Comment: @mukeshyadav: If you feel satisfied with the answer, don't stop at saying Thanks. You show your gratitude by _accepting_ the answer (tick-mark near the answer). See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)